# Cloudera 1 hosts scanned, 0 running SSH

Tags: ssh, configuration, cloudera

i'm trying to install cloudera manager on Ubuntu 14.04

Howerver when i want to add my host in the CDH cluster installation i get the following error :

[image]

it's strange because i did install set up ssh using the following commands :

```
# ssh-keygen
# cd ~/.ssh
# cat id_rsa.pub > authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to scan and find hosts, Cloudera requires SSH running on port 22. There could be a many reasons Cloudera isn't finding your host on this port, to include network misconfiguration, SSH Daemon (sshd) not running, sshd misconfigured, among others. The SSH key you've generated won't be useful until you can establish this SSH connection.

Try the following

```
nmap -p 22 hostname
```

If this is running your output should be similar to:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

This means sshd is running and open on 22, in which case there is another problem I'm unable to help with. Below is how to get sshd running and the following link should help with configuring the network on your Cloudera server/agents:

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_11_1.html

**sshd not running:**

You'll want to make sure it is running by executing the command

```
sudo service sshd status
```

If it is not running, go ahead and try

```
sudo service sshd start
```

If you get an error such as 'sshd: unrecognized service', you'll want to install it using your native package manager, apt-get, or or the synaptic package manager.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

check the following site for more information on setting up openssh-server (sshd)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring